# Using Batteries in .mly file with ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocaml-batteries, menhir

I have a project with OCaml .ml files and a Menhir .mly file. I use ocamlbuild to compile the project.

My _tags file contains this single line:

```
true: use_menhir, package(batteries)
```

Everything works well, except when I want to use Batteries in the .mly file. If I `open Batteries ;;` between `%{` and `%}` in my .mly file, I get "Error: Unbound module Batteries" when calling ocamlbuild.

It seems that when ocamlbuild is calling menhir, like this:

```
/usr/bin/menhir --ocamlc '/usr/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc' --infer parser.mly
```

it forgets to add `-package batteries` (or something equivalent) in the `--ocamlc` option of menhir.

How can I fix that? Maybe a special rule for my .mly file in my _tags file could help? Or is it a ocamlbuild bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is supposedly fixed in recent OCaml versions (see http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5763). Which version are you running?

Comment: I'm using OCaml 4.00.1, Batteries 2.1, and ocamlbuild 4.00.1.
These are the most recent released versions. I don't want to be working with the SVN version so I guess I'm stuck with the bug for now. Thanks for clearing out the situation.

Comment: Yes. With svn version:
`menhir --explain --infer -la 1 --table --ocamlc 'ocamlfind ocamlc -I +ocamlbuild -g -annot -bin-annot -strict-sequence -bin-annot -package yojson -package menhirLib -package ulex -package pprint -package fix -I parsing -I utils -I typing -I interpreter -I lib -I compiler -I mezzolib -I tests/unit' --infer parsing/grammar.mly
`

with 4.00.1:
`+ menhir --explain --infer -la 1 --table --ocamlc '/home/jonathan/.opam/4.00.1/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -I parsing -I utils -I typing -I interpreter -I lib -I compiler -I mezzolib -I tests/unit' --infer parsing/grammar.mly
`

Answer (score 5):

Before the next OCaml release, there is a good work-around described in the link given by Jonathan. If your `.mly` file is named `foo.mly`, you can define a `foo.mlypack` file with the following content:

```
Foo
```

Producing `foo.ml` will then use the `.mlypack` file (originally meant to support menhir's modular grammar combination feature), which will correctly pass the compilation options to the `--infer` parameter -- because `.mlypack` compilation was fixed long ago.

Comment: Haha. Dirty as hell. I like it. Thanks Gabriel.